# Disable asking for password when I open VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since a couple of days ago and the latest VS Code update, unlock your login keyring prompt appears on VS Code start-up (which had never happened before).

How to disable the prompt?

VS code is used stand-alone on a single-user laptop, without GIT or shared directories, or npm use.
Please note that VS Code has been running on the same machine with the same set-up for 1.5 years but the prompt only started a couple of days ago.

*Ubuntu 23.04 Wayland

Version: 1.80.0

OS: Linux x64 6.2.0-24-generic snap*

PS. Few days ago, I clicked a URL in a file opened by VS Code to open in Firefox. Could that have caused the change?

Comment: Git? OneDrive? Shared directory? Some more info about your environment would help.

Comment: @CodeCaster Post updated with further info.

Comment: Same here, same OS. "Escape" closes it but it re-opens, clicking "Cancel" closes it and it stays closed. But it shows up again on the next start-up.